# Jquery: Adding toggle action to drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create my own drop down navigation that expands when an arrow is clicked (for now just a > within a span)

My script cycles through a series of `<li>`s and checks if any have a child `<ul>` within them. If a `<ul>` is detected it then appends `<span class='submenuarrow'> ></span>` to the parent `<li>` so the user can click something to expand the menu. This works ok up until the toggle - the submenarrow span appears but does nothing when clicked.

Is this because I am using find to locate the an appended element? Im I doing anything else wrong?

My full script is:

```
$("#menu ul li").each(function() { 

var sub = $(this).find("ul");

//IF UL IS DETECTED
if (sub.size() > 0) {

//APPENDS ARROW TO LI
$(this).append("<span class='submenuarrow'> ></span>");

//ADDS TOGGLE
$(this).find("span").click(function() {
   $(this).find("ul").toggle("slow");
});//END TOGGLE    

}//END IF

});//END EACH
```

Comment: **Use:** `.append("<span class='submenuarrow'> &gt; </span>");`

Comment: Thanks - your syntax is correct but it makes no difference to the issue

Comment: That was a comment, not an answer ;)

Comment: ah sorry - there was another comment that was removed

Comment: @MeltingDog I deleted my answer, sorry, about that, misunderstood your question, I'll give it another look.

Comment: Also, can could you make a quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to showcase your problem? Could make it easier to pinpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple using the `:has()` selector!

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/awevay/1/edit)*

```
$('#menu li:has(ul)').each(function() {   
    $(this).append( "<span class='submenuarrow'> &gt; </span>" );  
});

$('#menu').on('click','.submenuarrow',function() {
    $(this).prev("ul").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Will work also with:

```
$('.submenuarrow').on('click',function() {
    $(this).prev("ul").slideToggle("slow");
});
```